# Font awesome icon not showing in storybook iconography vue

Tags: vue.js, storybook

I'm trying to make a iconography with storybook for all the icons in my vue project.
I just want to use icons from font awesome.

My main.ts file looks like:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome'
import { faUserSecret } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
library.add(faUserSecret)

createApp(App)
.component('font-awesome-icon', FontAwesomeIcon)
.mount('#app')
```

The storybook file (iconography.stories.mdx):

```
import { Meta, Title, IconGallery, IconItem } from '@storybook/addon-docs/';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome'
import { faUserSecret } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'

<Meta title="Design Tokens/Iconography" />

# Iconography

<IconGallery>
  <IconItem name="user-secret">
    <font-awesome-icon icon="fa-solid fa-user-secret" />
  </IconItem>
</IconGallery>
```

The icon is not showing just a box for it:
[image]

Comment: Just feedback, when you globally imported the font awesome in `main.ts` then you don't need to re-import it in any other file. Also, did you try its array syntax?

Comment: Can you show me? I thought I had to import it again in Storybook

Answer (score 4):

You need to setup fontawesome in your storybook `preview.js` file. There you can add the following:

```
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';
import { fas } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

library.add(fas);
```

then, your story would look something like this:

```
import { Meta, Title, IconGallery, IconItem } from '@storybook/addon-docs/';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';

<Meta title="Iconography" />

# Iconography

<IconGallery>
  <IconItem name="user-secret">
    <FontAwesomeIcon icon="user-secret" />
  </IconItem>
</IconGallery>
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Now to figure out how to mix free solid and pro sharp icons.

Answer (score 1):

There is actually another option in addition to installing and importing the library in preview.js as mentioned in the other post from @edin0x.

You can create the file .storybook/preview-header.html. Here you could just import font awesome via URL. This might be especially useful in case you don't want or can't use the lib specific FontAwesomeIcon component and instead want to use plain html or you want to include a pro kit.

```
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/xxxx.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Consequently, you can just use the html snippet like this:

```
<i class="fa-solid fa-angle-down"></i>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to give another possibility, I simply include the free fontawesome version like so in the `./storybook/preview.js` file and it works perfectly.

```
// Add font awesome
import "fontawesome-free/js/all.js";
```